# Missing row with Google BigQuery when using permanent external table pointing to GCS file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm working with BigQuery and experementing with using it to query a CSV file in a bucket in Google Cloud Storage. I came across some strange behavior where -- only when there are 3 rows in the CSV, and the first row contains a string in any field -- when querying the table, the first row is missing.

### Steps to reproduce:

#### Create `myfile.csv`:

```
testin,2,2
testing3,3,4
```

#### Copy file to GCS:

```
gsutil cp myfile.csv gs://bucket/
```

#### Create external table pointing to `gs://bucket/myfile.csv`:

```
bq mk --external_table_definition=Field1:STRING,Field2:STRING,Field3:INTEGER@CSV=gs://bucket/myfile.csv dataset.table
```

#### Query the table to ensure it's working:

```
bq query "SELECT * FROM dataset.table;"
```

#### Should output the following:

```
Waiting on biquery_job_id_1234567 ... (0s) Current 
status: DONE
+----------+--------+--------+
|  Field1  | Field2 | Field3 |
+----------+--------+--------+
| testin   | 2      |      2 |
| testing3 | 3      |      4 |
+----------+--------+--------+
```

### All good to move on to the bug..

#### Change `myfile.csv` to look like the following:

```
1,h,3
testin,2,2
testing3,3,4
```

#### Overwrite `gs://bucket/myfile.csv`:

```
gsutil cp myfile.csv gs://bucket/
```

#### Query `dataset.table` again:

```
bq query "SELECT * FROM dataset.table;"
```

#### Outputs:

```
Waiting on bigquery_job_78901234 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
+----------+--------+--------+
|  Field1  | Field2 | Field3 |
+----------+--------+--------+
| testin   | 2      |      2 |
| testing3 | 3      |      4 |
+----------+--------+--------+
```

### Lets make sure that the GCS file has the correct data:

```
gsutil cat gs://bucket/myfile.csv
```

#### Outputs:

```
1,h,3
testin,2,2
testing3,3,4
```

## Ok, interesting.

#### Change that middle value in the top row so that `myfile.csv` looks as follows:

```
1,2,3
testin,2,2
testing3,3,4
```

#### Overwrite the GCS file:

```
gsutil cp myfile.csv gs://bucket/
```

#### Query the table:

```
bq query "SELECT * FROM dataset.table;"
```

#### Outputs:

```
Waiting on bigquery_job_4567890 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
+----------+--------+--------+
|  Field1  | Field2 | Field3 |
+----------+--------+--------+
| 1        | 2      |      3 |
| testin   | 2      |      2 |
| testing3 | 3      |      4 |
+----------+--------+--------+
```

Does anyone have any insight as to what scenarios may cause the first row to become missing if it contains a string within the first 2 fields?

Thanks,

Comment: Even without setting skipLeadingRows the first row shouldn't be skipped since it matches the table schema. You can open a bug in the public BigQuery issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0

Comment: @Daria, will do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a parameter called [csvOptions.skipLeadingRows](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#externalDataConfiguration.csvOptions.skipLeadingRows) which is used to specify the number of "header rows" in a CSV file.

If `skipLeadingRows` is unspecified, BigQuery tries to autodetect the number of header rows. Setting `skipLeadingRows` manually to 0 should disable this behavior.

Comment: That fixed the issue. Thanks. 

But as @Daria mentioned, it does seem to be some sort of unexpected behavior beyond this fix.

Please see the issue I've opened on their [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73298327).